# How to select a selenium element with javascript that is an external variable

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to select an element using protractor with selenium but the element I want to take from an external variable that's in a json. How can I do that? The next example I am using is incorrect as it uses $data and not where $data points to.

Thank you!

programs.json

```
{ "programs":"One , Two"}
```

log.ts

```
const loginDato = require('../../../../../e2e/src/data/programs.json');
var data = loginDato['programs'][1];
element(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(),$data)]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find out and post it in case anyone has the same problem:

programs.json

```
{ "programs":["One" , "Two"]}
```

log.ts

```
var data = loginDato['programs'][1];
element(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+data+"')]"));
```